# Laravel Datatables advanced search - Ajax always returns default value from dropdown list

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, datatables

I have been trying to create a drop down filter for my laravel database following [this](https://datatables.yajrabox.com/fluent/advance-filter) example. However, my code always returns the default value from the dropdown list even through the url query changes correctly eg *homestead.app/?search_group_filter=variables* but my code always returns the default value of url.

php controller

```
public function globalFilter(Request $request)
{
    $tags = Unknown_Tag::groupBy('url');
    $datatables = Datatables::of($tags);

    debugbar::warning($request->get('searchGroup'));//both return url
    debugbar::warning($request->searchGroup);
    if ($name = $request->get('searchGroup')) {
        $datatables->where($request->searchGroup, 'like', 'http://b.scorecardresearch.com/p?c1=9');
    }
    return $datatables->make(true);
}
```

javascript

```
<script>
$(function() {
    var table = $('#ut-table');
    table.dataTable({
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        ajax: {
            url: 'http://homestead.app/globalFilter',
            data: function (d) {
                d.searchGroup = $('select[name=search_group_filter]').val();
            }
        },
        columns: [
            { data: 'protocol'},
            { data: 'domain'},
            ...
        ]
    });
    $('#search_group_filter').on('submit', function(e) {
        table.draw();
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<table border="0" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5">
    <tbody>
    Search
    <tr>
        <form>
        <select name='search_group_filter', id='search_group_filter'>
            <option value='url'>Full URL</option>
            <option value='protocol'>Protocol</option>
            <option value='domain'>Domain</option>
            <option value='path'>Path</option>
            <option value='query'>Full Query</option>
            <option value='variables'>Variables</option>
            <option value='values'>Values</option>
            <option value='occurrences'>Occurences</option>
        </select>
        <button type="submit">search</button>
        </form>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

EDIT:
Changing my routes to `Route::get('/globalFilter/{searchGroup}', 'DatatablesController@globalFilter');` from `Route::get('/globalFilter', 'DatatablesController@globalFilter');` and changing my AJAX call to this `http://homestead.app/globalFilter/groupSearch` replacing group search with the actual value, gives me the exact same thing. If I manually change my route, nothing changes either

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's this line. But not sure.

```
$datatables->where($request->searchGroup, 'like', 'http://b.scorecardresearch.com/p?c1=9')
```

It seems you hard coded that part, so it never changes.

**Updates**

Found your issue here

```
homestead.app/?search_group_filter=variables
```

You call it `search_group_filter`, not `searchGroup`

Comment: Its the first part that changes ($request->searchGroup). Plus, if I print out ($request->searchGroup) it always returns url. So I don't think thats it. The second part is hard coded for now so I can solve the problem one step at a time.

Comment: Check my updates. you are using the wrong name. `search_group_filter` not `searchGroup`